# Radio button condition ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I am having some issues with this code. I am trying to create an "advance" search for my database. Requesting two types of data (film and location). The location one work flawlessly and displays all the cinemas near to a location. But is it possible to do so with entering in a specific name of a movie?

```
Location Controller:
if params[:allcinemas].checked?
  if params[:search].present?
    @locations = Location.near(params[:search], 10, :order => :distance)
    @title = "Search Results:"
  else
    @locations = Location.joins(:cinema).order("cinemas.name").all
    @title = "Locations of Cinemas"   
  end
elsif params[:allmovies].checked?
  if params[:search].present?
    @films = Film.near(params[:search], :order => :title)
  else
    @films = Film.find(:all, :order => "title") 
  end
```

This is the Show.Html.erb for the locations

```
show.html.erb
<p>
 <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
 <%= submit_tag "Search Nearby Cinemas", :name => nil %>
 <br><%= radio_button_tag 'allcinemas', 'cinemas', true %> Cinemas
 <br><%= radio_button_tag 'allmovies', 'movies' %> Movies
</p>
```

Comment: didn't quite get your question, can you be more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: Sure, I have a a search field that only searches for the nearest cinemas in accordance to google so (postcode, places of interests). What i am trying to achieve is giving 2 more options under the submit button, allowing users to pick (movies or cinemas). In simple terms, if movie radio button is checked and if there is a search entered, then find the movies according to title. Else, find all the movies. Else if, if user has checked cinemas, then find the nearest cinema, elseif find them all. End

Answer (score 0):

Your radio_button_tags should 've the same name, something like:

`<%= radio_button_tag 'radio_input', 'cinemas', true %> Cinemas`
`<%= radio_button_tag 'radio_input', 'movies' %> Movies`

Now, in you controller radio_input.checked? will always return true since you default one choice with checked.  So, instead of this check : `if params[:allcinemas].checked?`

check for the value returned by params[:radio_input]:
`if params[:radio_button] == 'cinemas'`
 `#your logic to handle cinemas`
`else`
`#your logic for movies`

That should solve your problem.